# How to move changes from a git remote branch to a new branch

Tags: git

I created  `my-feature-branch` branch from our `develop` branch, committed my changes to it and raised a PR to merge it back to `develop`.

However, boss said, what I should have done is, created a `my-feature-branch` from `develop` , then created a `my-story-branch` off `my-feature-branch`, committed my changes to `my-story-branch` and raised a PR to merge `my-story-branch` back to `my-feature-branch`.

When all the stories of `my-feature-branch` have been completed, then it will be merged back to `develop`.

So, to fix this, I thought of doing like this:

1. manually copy my changes (12 files in total) to someplace else in my computer
2. delete all branches I created
3. Create `my-feature-branch` again, and then create `my-story-branch` off it
4. manually paste my changes
5. commit and raise PR

Is there a shorter way to accomplish this without deleting branches and manually copy pasting my changes ?

**EDIT**:

```
what I did (current state of my git - changes have been pushed to remote)
------------------------------------
    x-x-x (develop)
         \
          x-x' (my-feature-branch)

The above should now be changed to:
----------------------------------
x-x-x (develop)
         \
          x (my-feature-branch)
           \
            x-x' (my-story-branch)

And then raise a PR to merge my-story-branch to my-feature-branch
```

Comment: what your boss asked for sounds _way_ more complicated than what you did --- also, may you share a simple commit tree of your repo so we can better understand the issue?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Please see edit

Comment: Thank you for editing. That makes it a lot clearer!

Comment: `x (my-feature-branch)` do you know what content should be here? Or will it be an empty commit?

Comment: I think its just a new branch to hold "all" stories of the feature (I'm working on just one of the story). So, i think it was like: git checkout develop; git checkout -b my-feature-branch; git checkout -b my-story-branch and the merge my-story-branch back to my-feature-branch

Comment: That would work. I don't see a reason why you can't do that

Comment: How ? I have already committed my changes to `my-feature-branch` directly and pushed them to remote ? How can i undo it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have already pushed `my-feature-branch` to the remote (assuming `origin`) we should probably remove that. Make sure that no-one else is using that branch.

```sh
git push -d origin/my-feature-branch
# (if force has to be used)
# git push -f -d origin/my-feature-branch
```

We can rename the local `my-feature-branch` to be `my-story-branch` and push that.

```sh
git checkout my-feature-branch
git branch -m my-story-branch
git push origin my-story-branch
```

And because we still need `my-feature-branch` to merge into, we can create that and push it too.

```sh
git checkout develop
git checkout -b my-feature-branch
git push origin my-feature-branch
```

A simplified git tree should look like this:

```
x-x-x (develop)(my-feature-branch)
         \
          x-x-x' (my-story-branch)
```

Once `my-story-branch` has been merged with `my-feature-branch` it should look like this:

```
x-x-x (develop)-x (my-feature-branch)(my-story-branch)
         \     /
          x-x-x'
```

Comment: The biggest thing that changed how I view git is knowing that commits are snapshots and branches are little more than temporary labels which point to a commit.